# R Markdown Chunk and Moving Around Directories

Tags: r, r-markdown

If my R Markdown document is located in `"documents/report.Rmd"` how do I call source files located in `"source_files/script1.R"` or `"source_files/script2.R"`. I use Linux and Windows. We might as well include the answer for OS X as well for all the Mac users out there. If I didn't know any better I'd put this in a markdown chunk:

```
cd ..
source("source_files/script1.R")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command

`knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = "path/to/project/directory")`

I like to use Rstudio, so I would set the `root.dir` to where my .Rproj file is located. Then you can treat directories like any other project and just use relative paths from `root.dir` to refer to them.

Note that this command should go in your first code chunk, i.e., something like the following

````
```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = "path/to/dir/")
```
````

and no other commands should be in this setup chunk that expect this new directory. You should start a second chunk to use your `source` commands

Comment: Isn't the first rule of reproducible research *'don't use directory paths'*? If my path is `c:\windows\user290\mydocuments` and yours is `macOS\macDesktop` then you won't be able to run my code? Correct?

Comment: @stackinator Yes, you're right that this does violate the idea of RR. Using Rmd files with complex directory structures is not always a trivial task. You may want to check out Jenny's gist [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:fnJ0acv1VTEJ:https://gist.github.com/jennybc/362f52446fe1ebc4c49f+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=nz)